# JBoss AS 7 - After Startup initialization

Tags: java, jboss, web.xml

Is there any way to catch an event/implements a Class, or something like that, to detect that JBoss (AS7) is up and running and all applications has been deployed ?

I made a StartupServlet (which extends HttpServlet) because i need to call a local web service to initialize the system. But because my application is not fully deployed my call for the web service (in the StartupServlet) ends in a "404 Not Found error".

I tried to use a `<listener>...</listener>` on the web.xml but it's not working.

Answer (score 0):

You can try using a `Startup` EJB, like explained [here](http://blog.eisele.net/2010/12/seven-ways-to-get-things-started-java.html):

```
@Singleton
@Startup
public class StartupBean {

  @PostConstruct
  private void startup() { ... }

  @PreDestroy
  private void shutdown() { ... }
}
```

However the bean will not detect whether your applications are deployed, only that the current application - the one containing the bean - is deployed and started. Since the `@PostConstruct` method is called very early, you cannot rely on any other beans or services being available.

**EDIT**: Jboss also has a [native management API](https://docs.jboss.org/author/display/AS71/The+native+management+API). AFAIK it can also be used to query deployments. Unfortunately it's documentation is not really impressive, but perhaps  you can figure it out.

Comment: I tried, but it's called way to early.. I starting to think there is not way to do this.

Comment: @Joshua - at least it is not trivial. I have added one more possibility - perhaps it can help.

Answer (score 0):

According to my understanding, you do not need to detect when all application was deployed, you need to understand only if your application was deployed. To do it you should define ServletContextListener:
http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/api/javax/servlet/ServletContextListener.html#contextInitialized%28javax.servlet.ServletContextEvent%29

Than you can catch when it deployed:

```
public void contextInitialized(ServletContextEvent sce)
{
      servletContext = sce.getServletContext();
}
```